# How to get all data record count in one database?

Tags: postgresql

For PostgreSQL database, there is a very big database includes lots of tables and records.
I want to get all the record count for all the tables in a smart way instead of select count one by one.
Is there a good way?
And I only want to get the data count in public schema.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get an exact count except by counting all the rows in all the tables.

If an approximate result will do, you can use the statistics:

```
SELECT sum(reltuples) FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'r';
```

This includes the catalog tables that contain the metadata of the database. These typically are not very large, but you can exclude them by filtering on the `relnamespace` column.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596670/how-do-you-find-the-row-count-for-all-your-tables-in-postgres) on StackOverflow which gives 21 answers to this question - the best of them (IMHO) is this one by [Daniel Vérité](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709658) who's handy with PostgreSQL. All of the code below is to be found on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/oxva4Yx1).

The solution is nice in that

- a) it gives an exact count (this will be expensive for a large system!)
- b) he gives a very thorough explanation as to the logic behind his answer

Basically, he creates a function and uses this to iterate through the tables in a given schema (and indeed, schemas if you so desire).

```
CREATE FUNCTION rowcount_all(schema_name TEXT DEFAULT 'public')
  RETURNS TABLE(table_name text, cnt bigint) AS
$$
DECLARE
  table_name TEXT;
BEGIN
  
  FOR table_name IN 
    SELECT c.relname 
    FROM pg_class c
      JOIN pg_namespace s ON (c.relnamespace = s.oid)
    WHERE c.relkind = 'r' 
      AND s.nspname = schema_name
  LOOP
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT CAST(%L AS TEXT), COUNT(*) FROM %I.%I',
       table_name, schema_name, table_name);
  END LOOP;
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgsql;
```

So, I'll go through the function, partly for general explanation, partly to explain it to myself! :-) I have two tables (city, country) with 2 & 3 records respectively.

First, we have:

```
SELECT c.relname 
FROM pg_class c
  JOIN pg_namespace s ON (c.relnamespace = s.oid)
WHERE c.relkind = 'r' 
  AND s.nspname = 'public';
```

Result:

```
relname
   city
country
```

This is then wrapped in the function body which loops through the `relname`s and gets a `COUNT(*)` of them.

```
SELECT 
  n,
  rowcount_all(n)  -- passing n from the subquery to rowcount_all()
FROM 
  (SELECT 'public' AS n) AS t;  -- could use `VALUES` clause also
```

Result:

```
n   rowcount_all
public  (city,2)
public  (country,3)
```

note that `rowcount_all` returns a `TABLE` - in this case with one row for each table in your schema. This can be simplified (see fiddle) as we know that the default schema for the function is `public` which is the one that you want - of course, this can be modified. Daniel's `VALUES` clause allows you to input as many as you like.

Now, we draw it all together:

```
WITH rc (schema_name,tbl) AS 
(
  SELECT 
    s.n,
    rowcount_all(s.n) 
  FROM (VALUES ('public')) AS s(n)
)
SELECT 
  schema_name,
  (tbl).* 
FROM rc;
```

Result:

```
schema_name   table_name    cnt
     public         city      2
     public      country      3
```

And finally:

```
--
-- Warning! Will be expensive on large systems!
--

SELECT 
  SUM(cnt) AS "Grand total"
FROM
(
  WITH rc (schema_name,tbl) AS 
  (
    SELECT 
      s.n,
      rowcount_all(s.n) 
    FROM (VALUES ('public')) AS s(n)
  )
  SELECT 
    schema_name,
    (tbl).* 
  FROM rc
) AS sub;
```

Result:

```
Grand total
          5
```

*Et voilà*. There are, as mentioned above, 21 solutions on the StackOverflow thread taking different approaches (statistical (like @LaurenzAlbe's answer), bash &c...) -  worth looking at if you want to learn - they gave me some insights into how the problem might be tackled in different ways.